# Distupgrade issues. Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade

So, as we all know, all great sagas begin with 'I did a distupgrade'

Everything started fine while still in the Ubuntu 16.04 environment, but stalled after a 'whole heap of stuff' had been written to disc.

I restart the computer, but to no avail, the CPU stalls. I'm using a Dell XPS from 2017.

I create a Ubuntu 18.04 usb boot stick and try to boot into the usb Ubuntu environment. The CPU stalls.

I try my friends Ubuntu 14.04 boot stick and try to boot it. The computer finds /boot but promptly issues a 'kernel panic'

I create a Ubuntu 16.04 boot stick and lo and behold it boots into the usb Ubuntu environment.

I make a copy of my old system on an external drive. My valuable home folder is encrypted, but that is another issue.

I reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 on my XPS and now I can boot and launch the system. I try to upgrade to 18.04 and again: the CPU stalls.

My question is: why does the CPU stall when I try to boot 18.04 but not other Linux OS or Ubuntu 16.04 ?

All the best
Richard

Comment: This seems to be related to:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/8f9sme/ubuntu_1804_on_xps_9560/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what I did was:

Wiped the drive doing repartitioning and formating.
Booting into the Ubuntu USB 18.04 environment now worked.
Installing Ubuntu 18.04 from the USB.

At reboot the old issue reappeared. Everything stalled. After reboot got to the boot options and I could boot into the recovery environment.
In the recovery menu selected 'fsck' option.
Then tried a normal boot and I could now boot into the newly installed Ubuntu 18.04 on disk.

Edited:

```
sudo nano -w /etc/default/grub
```

Added:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"
```

saved the file.
Then I ran:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now I can properly boot into my Ubuntu OS